# Rounded sides with sharp corners

Tags: html, css, css-shapes, rounded-corners

I'm looking to achieve these sides on an element with CSS:

[image: screenshot]

This is the closest I've got (border is required):

[image: screenshot]

```css
div { 
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-top-left-radius: 200px 300%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 200px 300%;
  border-top-right-radius: 200px 300%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 200px 300%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Any suggestions on how to sharpen the edges? Width needs to be variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with pseudo elements, like this, and it will scale to what ever size you set on the main element

*Updated*

`typ2` has equal radius on the left/right curved border, if you want to fill these with a color, or image, or dynamically scalable height, an extra inner element is required.

```css
.typ1 div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 120px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 30px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.typ1 div + div { 
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.typ1 div::before,
.typ1 div::after { 
  left: 0;
  top: -10%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 120%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.typ1 div::after { 
  left: 22%;
  top: 0;
  width: 56%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0;
  border-width: 1px 0;
}

.typ2 div { 
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 74px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px 52px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-width: 1px 0;
}

.typ2 div + div { 
  width: 156px;
}

.typ2 div::before,
.typ2 div::after { 
  left: -24px;
  top: -25%;
  width: 188px;
  height: 150%;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
}
.typ2 div::after { 
  left: auto;
  right: -24px;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

/* general styling */
div::before, div::after { 
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="typ1">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>

<div class="typ2">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: `.typ2` is exactly what I'm after. Nice idea to use pseudo-elements like this, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

If you know the size that you want the shape to be, you can use a wrapper div and overflow: hidden to solve this.

I use flexbox to center it, but you can use other ways to center it vertically.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle { 
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the `:before` and `:after` *pseudo-elements*:

```css
.circle { 
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000;
}

.circle:before,
.circle:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 25px;
  background: #fff;
}

.circle:before {
  top: -16px;
}

.circle:after {
  bottom: -16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle"></div>
```

Adjust the *values* of the `top` and `bottom` *properties* as you wish.